# Magento 2.1 DB transaction error

Tags: magento2, database, exception

I need to insert some records in custom table as a transaction in product save after observer and do some actions if not all inserted see code below:

```
//Read rows from uploaded csv file in $sql_str_arr
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sqlStatment = "INSERT INTO `My_Table` (`serial`, `pin`, `product_id`) VALUES "
.implode(',', $sql_str_arr).';';

try{
 $ret = $conn->rawQuery($sqlStatment);
  $conn->commit();
  $qty += count($sql_str_arr);
}
catch(Exception $e)
  $conn->rollback();
  $qty = 0;
}
//Update stock and remove the file
```

It gives error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions
>   have not been committed or rolled back

What is the error here and How to make it work or even handle the exception log.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you import some Exception class.

try replace your code with (I add `\` before exception)

```
try{
 $ret = $conn->rawQuery($sqlStatment);
  $conn->commit();
  $qty += count($sql_str_arr);
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
  $conn->rollback();
  $qty = 0;
}
```

Also pay attention that your code can have sql injection. Maybe better to use `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::insertArray` method for insert data in table